# Can I still use my bathrooms if my sump pump is broken?

Tags: plumbing

My sump pump has gone out. We have a bathroom in the basement and our laundry room is downstairs. My question is will we be able to use the upstairs bathrooms until we can get the sump pump fixed? Or another way to express my concerns: Is the upstairs plumbing affected by the downstairs plumbing in regards to the sump pump?

Answer (score 4):

The sump collects water from around and under your foundation. It has nothing to do with your plumbing.

If you have a sewage ejector, that would be a different story.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem, unless you actually need the pump to move water out of the sump.